# Opening a webpage in webView from tableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, uiwebview

Ok, so i've scoured google and this site for code snippets but none of them seem to work. The tableview navigates to a new view, with a webview in it.
The header says

```
@interface WebViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
UIWebView *_webView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

Then we have the viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
//    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.co.uk"]]];
            NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.co.uk";
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
            NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

As you can see, i've tried 2 different methods that i could find. The view is loading but it is not loading the website.
On the NIB the webView has Outlets - delegate - File's Owner and Referencing Outlets - webView - File's Owner also webView = _webView is synthesized.

As far as i can see everything is linked up and i'm stumped as to why it doesn't work! Halp? ^_^

If this cannot be sorted, can anyone recommend a better way to navigate to a webview from a tableview?

Anyone?

Comment: does your webView call - (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error delegate method, and what code you write in webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: method?

Comment: No i don't have either of those methods (Sorry i'm quite new, only been doing this 2 weeks) When i put the error one in it just says 'expected identifier'

Comment: Ok seems like i have sorted that error, i've got both of those methods in, what do i need to put in them? Sorry to sound so useless lmao

Comment: in - (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error method, try to put NSLog(@"%@", [error description]); and set break point next to this line, to see what going bad.

Comment: Not getting any errors in debug console at all... In fact the method isn't being called at all.. o.O

Comment: try to set delegate directly in viewDidLoad method webView.delegate = self; before call loadRequest method, maybe this will help, and check if your webView == nil in viewDidLoad

Comment: There is nothing stating webView == nil, i cannot put that code in and NSLOG can't check webView! I've put the delegate setting in and still doesn't load >.<

Comment: in viewDidLoad put next code NSLog(@"%@", self.webView); If it will write "(null)" in output, then problem in it, also try to clean your project in Product -> Clean

Comment: 2012-08-23 15:26:22.114 TableView[859:707] <UIWebView: 0xfe0ab90; frame = (0 0; 320 460); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xfe1bc30>>
Will clean now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I implement a UIWebView I typically do the following in my header file:

```
//.h
//XIB UIWebView has a single outlet to the IBOutlet below

@interface WebViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWebView *webView;



//.m
//The only difference, and it's somewhat semantics, is the following

[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
webView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if only i could remember which project it was haha! Must've got some in-office help. Will pop the accept on as a ty :)